# Can the GPU in a 21.5 inch Mid 2011 iMac be upgraded to support 4k?

Tags: imac, upgrade, gpu

The computer comes with an AMD Radeon HD 6770M 512 MB discrete graphics card. According to [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht206587), the earliest iMac to support 4k is Late 2013. By then, I believe iMacs were using GeForce cards and I'm also not sure they're actually physically discrete, so I'm not sure I could just swap out the card for one in a later Mac. However, it also seems that there are firmware blocks on using non-mac GPUs in a Mac. Is there a way around this? I basically got a 2011 iMac for free and I want to use it at 4k with the monitor I already have.

Comment: The GPUs in iMacs are a special form factor and given that they're 8 years old now, it's highly unlikey you'll be able to upgrade to support 4K.

Comment: That's disappointing, but basically what I was expecting to hear.